# usecols in Python not reading the headings in my CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV with Headings in row 1, `Number` and `Arrival Date`, these are columns `0` and `8`.

When I write:

```
cv2 = pd.read_csv(honeyfile, skiprows=[0], header=None, usecols=[0,8])
```

It works fine.

however, I wanted to use a string in case more columns are ever added to the report and shifted the count.

I cut and paste the headings in from the CSV to make sure Case and white space were correct.

This is my code:

```
cv2 = pd.read_csv(honeyfile, skiprows=[0], header=None, usecols=['Number','Arrival Date'])
```

This returns a `ValueError` saying there are no matching columns with these names?
While the error points to this line, it should be noted that the next line of code renames them,

```
cv2.columns = ['Supply Number','Delivery Date']
```

This works fine when I use the numbers to target the columns. 
Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
cv2 = pd.read_csv(honeyfile, usecols=['Number','Arrival Date'])
```

because is necessary read header to columns names.

`skiprows=[0], header=None` remove columns names, so only working `usecols=[0,8]`.

Comment: Perfect, of course, it does. Utter wood for trees moment! Thanks :-)